# How to create model instance with a button and no forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with 2 fields, the first one is `user` and the second one is `member`.

I want to create an instance just clicking a button without filling a form. I want to get the I want to get the `user` from the logged user and the `member` from the current block in the HTML

This is my model:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):     
    member_proyect = models.ManyToManyField(Member, related_name=('vacancy'))     
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Member(models.Model):
    proyect = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rol =  models.CharField(verbose_name="Título", max_length=200)
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Contenido")
    skill = TaggableManager() 

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Título", max_length=200)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name="Contenido")
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Orden", default=0)
    category = models.CharField(verbose_name="Categoria", max_length=15, choices=CATEGORIES, default='Arte')
    country = CountryField(default='')
    duration = models.CharField(verbose_name="Duración", max_length=200, default='')
    target = models.CharField(verbose_name="Objetivo", max_length=100, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, validators=[URL_VALIDATOR], default='')
    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de edición")


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "página"
        verbose_name_plural = "páginas"
        ordering = ['order', 'title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to get the `user` from the logged user.

I did this for loop to display all the members in the HTML

```
{% for member in member_list %}
  {% if member.proyect_id == page.id %}
    {% with n=forloop.counter %}
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading{{n}}">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse{{n}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{n}}">
          {{member.rol}}
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapse{{n}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse " aria-labelledby="heading{{n}}" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          {{member.content |safe }}
          <form action="" method="post"> <!-- I want to click this button and create the instance -->
              {% csrf_token %}                        
              <input type="submit" value="Aplicar" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endwith %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, there is no form, just a button and I am not sure how to do it.

**Views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import Applicant, Page, Member
from .forms import PageForm, MemberForm, ApplicantForm
from .filters import PageFilter
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404

class PageListView(ListView):
    model = Page
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = PageFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self. get_queryset ())
        return context

class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Page

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Page
    form_class = PageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('members:create')

    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('members:create', args=[self.object.id]) 

    exclude = ['user']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PageUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Page
    form_class = PageForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('pages:update', args=[self.object.id]) + '?ok'

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PageDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Page
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')

#
# Aqui empieza Member
# 

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MemberCreate(CreateView):
    model = Member
    form_class = MemberForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')  

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project'] = self.kwargs['project']
        return context
    


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MemberUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Member
    form_class = MemberForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('members:update')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('members:update', args=[self.object.id]) + '?ok'

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MemberDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Member
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')
    


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ApplicantCreate(CreateView):
    model = Applicant
    form_class = ApplicantForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')

    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('pages:pages', args=[self.object.id]) 

    exclude = ['user']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['member'] = self.kwargs['member']
        return context
```

**Urls**

```
pages_patterns = ([
    path('', PageListView.as_view(), name='pages'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page'),
    path('create/', PageCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', PageUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', PageDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
], 'pages')

members_patterns = ([
    path('create/<int:project>', MemberCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', MemberUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', MemberDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
], 'members')

applicant_patterns = ([
    path('create/<int:member>', ApplicantCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
], 'applicants')
```

This is the URL that loads the HTML with the button

```
path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page'),
```

Comment: share your views.py

Comment: Hi, I added the code, I was trying to use `ApplicantCreate` to create the instance but I could not do it

Comment: also share the member_list model, so you can get correct answer

Comment: which view is related to the HTML?

Comment: Added the other models and the urls. and the path to the HTML where is the button